# Project from view(Bound)

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I am new to Blender and I am trying to map an image as a texture on top face of a mesh. I choose the view I am interested in (Top view) and use Project from view(bound). But I can also see the image on other sides of the shape, which is not desirable.

I cannot manually select the faces because the object is created by point cloud and consists of too many edges and faces.

Does anybody have any idea?

[image]

Comment: What if you use Numpad7, CTRL+Numpad7, Numpad3, CTRL+Numpad3, to view the faces from the sides and in that view just select all of them by dragging the selection rectangle?

Comment: Alternatively, you could select one face from each of the sides (the parts you don't want shaded) and go to the select menu at the top of the viewport and pick `select similar > normal` - this will select all the faces pointing in the same direction(s) as the ones you selected. Then you can give them a separate material.

Comment: Thanks! It worked:)

Answer (score 2):

You can tab into edit mode, select one face where you don't want the image to be, then hit **shift + G** select **co-planar**, it will select all the faces with the same normal (the same orientation).
Then you can use the option of the threshold to allow faces with a pretty much similar orientation to be selected,
Then you can finally use the search bar to extend your selection if needed.
depending the orientation of the other faces of you mesh you will have some cleaning to do, but this method should make things easier and faster
[image]

[image]

[image]